# Python Newscatcher throws errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pip

When I try to install `Newscatcher` in the `Conda` virtual env (`Python 3.7.13`), it throws the following errors;
I tried the following way;

```
pip install git+https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher.git
```

Following is the error;

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher.git
  Cloning https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-d53hkjlh
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher.git /tmp/pip-req-build-d53hkjlh
  Resolved https://github.com/kotartemiy/newscatcher.git to commit b86b1a650241be4e82941319698e01a33c0c01ac
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.23.0 in ./anaconda3/envs/bot/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from newscatcher==0.2.0) (2.28.1)
Collecting tldextract<3.0.0,>=2.2.2
  Using cached tldextract-2.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting feedparser<6.0.0,>=5.2.1
  Using cached feedparser-5.2.1.zip (1.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in feedparser setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

If someone could explain me what is this error all about, I can solve it I guess. Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+use_2to3+is+invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you're trying to install is a bit old (3 years), however, setup tools [removed](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v58-0-0) support for `2to3` during builds.

Try downgrading `setup tools`:

```py
pip install "setuptools<58.0.0"
```

And then

```py
pip install newscatcher --upgrade
```